# Is it better to use switchMap or subscribe to the authState to get the currently logged in user in firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I've seen several different tutorials that explain how to check if a user is logged in but I can't understand which is better. Could someone explain in more detail the pros and cons of each method please? This is using an ionic 3 frontend and obviously firebase for the the backend using angularfire2.

This is what's inside the AuthProvider for the first method:

```
private _authState: firebase.User = null;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( state => {
      this._authState = state;
    });

get isAuthenticated() {
    return this._authState.uid !== null;
  }
```

This method is mentioned in the firebase docs. There's also another method which uses switchMap like here:

```
user: Observable<User>;

 constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null);
        }
      });
  }
```

Then you just access the user observable directly. Is there one which is better practice to use or does it even matter?

Answer (score 0):

I think using switchMap is a better approach because your user and auth state are managed by the Observable. You then can grab your user whenever like:

```
getUser(): Promise<User> {
    return this.user.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
}
```

And check auth state with a function by checking if theres a user object in the observable and doing a double bang on it:

```
isLoggedIn(): Promise<any> {

    return this.user.pipe(
        take(1),
        map(user => !!user)
    )
    .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: You mentioned switchMap is better, but I didn't see it in your example code.  Assuming it's a typo, what's the point of a switchMap here in the context of angularfire?  Are new user's rolling in so often that it's necessary to switch to a new observable each time?  Could you also elaborate on the "take(1)"?